# Can I use the !important css keyword with Angularjs ng-style directive?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with **boostrap3** and it's **default background: transparent !important;** print setting. 
I have the need to show a heatmap in my webapp and have these printable.
I'm using an ng-style directive for that to dynamically calculate the needed background-color.
In short, this is the html part

```
<div class="heatmap" ng-style="scalecolor(10)">lorem ipsum</div>
```

and this is the controller part

```
$scope.scalecolor = function(perc) {
        return { backgroundColor: plnkUtils.scaleColorInt('#EE0000', '#88FF00', perc) }
    };
```

However, because bootstrap3 sets all backgrounds to transparent with the **!important** keyword, I can't print these.

This is the part of bootstrap 3.1.0 css causing the issue with missing background-color:

```
@media print {
  * {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
}
```

Since the inverse of background: transparent !important; is  background: color hex code !important; 
(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534548/override-background-transparent-important-in-twitter-bootstrap-css) )
I'm trying to set that using the ng-style, but then **the exclamantion mark causes Angularjs to flip** when I try this:

```
 $scope.scalecolor = function(perc) {
    return { backgroundColor: plnkUtils.scaleColorInt('#EE0000', '#88FF00', perc)  !important }
};
```

or alternatively when I try this in the html template

```
ng-style="scalecolor(10) !important"
```

***Anyone out there that knows how I can use the !important css keyword with the Angularjs ng-style directive to override the bootstrap3 wildcard?***

For those who want to see this with their own eyes,  [here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1M5dwP5mkT16gYkWwJM?p=preview) a plunker showing the issue

Comment: You should **always** try to avoid using !important.

Comment: Your Plunkr can't be found.

Comment: the problem is scalecolor returns an object, the second one is that `"scalecolor(10) !important"` is not really an expression (ng-style takes either object or an expression [maybe also array])

Comment: @David This should be solved.

Comment: Nope. I still can't get to it.

Comment: @Shomz well yes, but in this case that would mean I either need to get rid of bootstrap3 or overwrite it's css and leave cdn's aside.

Comment: Nope, still no access.

Comment: I'm able to get to that plunk without a problem

Comment: I'm having issues with Plunkr in general right now. It must be my network. This makes me sad.

Comment: why not just add a stylesheet of your own to override that rule? (use `!important`, too! fight fire with fire!)

Comment: @AardVark71 Sorry, didn't catch that bootstrap uses !important. That's weird, though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently you can't and it's a known issue but there is some workaround that can be found here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5379

***The solution below has been copied from the site just in case the link breaks, or get changed.***

You're not able to use the `!important` directive in the DOM style property in either Chrome nor FF (probably others too). The style attribute gets parsed as CSS, but the `HTMLElement.style` property doesn't. Unfortunately you're not able to set a property's priority here (in Gecko/Blink/Webkit, at least).

So, there are some workarounds here:

**Workaround #1**

```
<ANY data-ng-attr-style="{{ blue && 'background-color: blue!important' || '' }}">
</ANY>
```

This would be your best way to go in terms of browser-support, because the CSS property priority will get parsed correctly here.

**Workaround #2**

Alternatively, you can also do the following in javascript:

```
$scope.$watch(conditionalStyle);

function conditionalStyle() {
  if ($scope.blue) {
    $element[0].style.setProprety('background-color', 'blue', 'important');
  } else {
    $element[0].style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}
```

Where `$element` is a jQuery/jqLite object referencing an HTMLElement.

**Note**: caveats are not supported in IE < 9 so workaround #1 is probably your best bet for this behavior where you depend on property priority...

Comment: Yes, thanks. The workaround specified there works. I had to switch to using the ngAttr attribute bindings and (i) use ng-attr-style="{{scalecolor(10)}}" in the template and (ii) have scalecolor return 'background-color: ' + plnkUtils.scaleColorInt('#EE0000', '#88FF00', perc) + '!important';

Comment: I'm getting a "can't bind to 'ng-attr-style' since it isn't a known property of 'input'" error when I try and use this to apply a conditional style to an input with !important.

<input type="radio" formControlName="releaseNotesRadio" value="Yes" data-ng-attr-style="{{ 'displayMessage.releaseNotesRadio' ? 'background: #f7e8e9 !important ; border-color: #ae1100 !important' : 'background:#FFF; border-color: #00A221'}}">Yes

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 6):

Using the tips for @Wawy I updated my code to get it to work.
For anyone landing on this page, for clarification I made an updated Plunker that can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/056Pw5dPrekCMbk1ZtlV)

In short, this is now the html part

```
<div class="heatmap" ng-attr-style="{{ngAttrScaleColor(10)}}">YES, ng-attr-style works !</div>
```

and this is the controller part

```
$scope.ngAttrScaleColor = function(perc) {
        return  'background-color: ' + plnkUtils.scaleColorInt('#EE0000', '#88FF00', perc) + '!important';
 };
```