# ngStyle does not work with !important in angular2

Tags: angular

In angular2 template if I write:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'red'}"
```

it works as expected. 
But If I write:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'red !important'}"
```

it's not working (not showing any error also)

Comment: See a similar solution:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046704/can-i-use-the-important-css-keyword-with-angularjs-ng-style-directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046704/can-i-use-the-important-css-keyword-with-angularjs-ng-style-directive)

Comment: @G-Yo thanks for the link, [attr.style]="'background-color:red !important'" worked  for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As angular2 documentation is still not good enough, I think it may be helpful to post the solution as an answer (**may be it helps someone**).

According to angularjs (1.x) git repository [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5379)

> You're not able to use the !important directive in the DOM style
>   property in either Chrome nor FF (probably others too)

So instead of using !important in [ngStyle] I use the following way to make it work:

```
[attr.style]="'background-color:red !important'"
```

It works as expected.