# Styling inside *ngFor Dependent on Iteration

Tags: html, angular, security, xss, single-page-application

I'm struggling to produce a style inside an `*ngFor` based on the iteration. My template looks like this:

```
<div
    *ngFor="let color of options.colors"
    <!--attempt to apply style using color variable-->
>
</div>
```

Where options is simply an `object` with a property `color` of type `Array<string>`. These are the attempts I have made so far:

```
style="border-color: {{color}} !important"
style="{{'border-color: ' + color + ' !important'}}"
```

These both produce the following output in the console:

[image: sanitizing unsafe style value]

Angular.io outlines why this occurs [here](https://angular.io/guide/security#xss), citing the reason for this as protection against XSS attacks. The page does not break, but the colors are simply not applied; a default color in one of my CSS files is used instead.

I figured I would instead go about a more Angular-y method:

```
[style.border-color]="{{color}} !important"
[style.border-color]="{{color + ' !important'}}"
[ngStyle]="{ 'border-color': '{{color}} !important' }"
[ngStyle]="{{'{ border-color: ' + color + ' !important }'}}"
```

EDIT: also

```
[attr.style]="'border-color: {{color}} !important'"
```

But all of these attempts produced the following error or something similiar:

[image: error message in developer console]

(If it makes a significant difference, it was specifically the third of those attempts that threw this error.)

I have a very limited understanding of `[style.*characteristic*]` and `[ngStyle]`, and I can't seem to find anything online explaining how to use them inside an `*ngFor`.

Can anyone point me towards what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use interpolation in property binding. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35191379/4911842).

Comment: @developer033 Then what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

When you use property binding `[style.border-color]' the assigned value is a property. So you don't need interpolation.

Here is an example from my code:

```
                        <img *ngIf='showImage'
                             [src]='product.imageUrl'
                             [title]='product.productName | uppercase'
                             [style.width.px]='imageWidth' 
                             [style.margin.px]='imageMargin'>
```

Where imageWidth and imageMargin are properties.

So you would need something more like this:

```
[style.border-color]="color"
```

This binds to the color variable.

Comment: How would the OP inject the "!important" qualifier into the CSS rule? I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: @RobZuber Yeah, that's exactly the problem I'm facing. It's good to know that this works without it, but in this case I actually need it.

Comment: When setting a style on a specific element ... there should be no need for !important. And !important is considered "bad practice", see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: And if it is really needed ... put it in a CSS class and use the class on the element instead.

Comment: @DeborahK But it's dependent on an *ngFor; a CSS class won't cut it. And in this case, it doesn't work unless !important is used.

Comment: ngFor simply repeats an element. I don't understand what that has to do with how a style is applied? And why won't a css class work? And how does the inline style not work without the important attribute? Maybe more info? Or a plunker?

Comment: @DeborahK The issue is that each element in the *ngFor needs to have a different color applied based on the `color` variable established by the *ngFor. While the above solution works, it does not demonstrate how to apply the `!important` marker, which is needed in this case to override a different style elsewhere that also uses `!important`.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible.  I did some googling when I first replied to the question and found nothing. I asked during one of our Angular doc team meetings and no one at the meeting had any idea how to add !important to this either.