# how can apply !important in ngStyle in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have this tables  , and I need to apply color in header , but where used ngStyle & !important now working ,

```
 <div ng-app='my.app'>
                <table>
              <tr>
                <th ng-style="{'background-color': 'blue !important'}">Column 1</th>
                <th style="background-color: blue !important;">Column </th>
                <th style="background-color: blue !important;">Column </th>
                <th style="background-color: blue !important;">Column </th>
                <th style="background-color: blue !important;">Column </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
        
              </tr>
              
              <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>11</td>
        
              </tr>
              
              <tr>
                <td>111</td>
                <td>111</td>
                <td>111</td>
                <td>111</td>
                <td>111</td>
        
              </tr>
              
              <tr>
                <td>1111</td>
                <td>1111</td>
                <td>1111</td>
                <td>1111</td>
                <td>1111</td>
        
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

in above table is apply style header in 4 column  using below line

```
style="background-color: blue !important;"
```

but the first column  when used below line not working

```
ng-style="{'background-color': 'blue !important'}"
```

I try this lines to solved this issue  but not working :

```
- [attr.style]="'background-color:red !important'"
      not show erro but not working 

- ng-attr-style="{{'background-color: pink!important'}}   

   
      return this error : Can't bind to 'ng-attr-style' since it isn't a known property of 'th'. 
      ("pSortableColumn]="header.columnName"

- data-ng-attr-style="{{ blue && 'background-color: blue!important' || '' }}"
```

can have any idea to solved this issue , thanks for all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191379/ngstyle-does-not-work-with-important-in-angular2

Comment: @Numichi I check this solution and  used this line [attr.style]="'background-color:red !important'" but not working , .

Comment: How does it appear in the HTML code of the browser?

Comment: @Numichi please check my example and tell me the problems  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/xn6z18yd/16/)

Comment: I dont know what are you doing. What angular version have you? It is work at me.
`<div class="form-container" [attr.style]="'background-color:red !important'">`
to
`<div _ngcontent-elv-c232="" class="form-container" style="background-color:red !important">`