# ng-style in pre tag with !important not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```html
<pre ng-style="(errmessage) ? { 'width':'100%', color:'red !important' } : { 'width': '0%' }">{{errmessage}}</em></pre>
```

I want to override the colour of pre tag errormessage coming from directive {{errmessage}} to red using ng-style if errormessage is not empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use the !important css keyword with Angularjs ng-style directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046704/can-i-use-the-important-css-keyword-with-angularjs-ng-style-directive)

Answer (score 0):

better to use `ng-class` instead of `ng-style`

add two class in css:

```
.has-error {
  width:100%;
  color: red !important;
}
.no-error {
  width:0%;
}
```

and use it in html

```
<pre ng-class="errmessage ? 'has-error': 'no-error'">{{errmessage}}</pre>
```