# Override `background: transparent !important` for background-image in Twitter Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

I face the same problem mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20534548/3530081), but for `background-image`, the answer for that question only supports filling the whole `div` with a certain solid color not an image.

My case is that I have a group of `div`s that I give each a different `background-image` like the following:

```css
@media print {
  .AdultDentalChart .tooth .toothImage1 {
    background-image: url("@Url.Content("~/images/DentalChart.png")") !important;
    background-position: 0px 10px;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
```

Bear in mind that I am facing the same code in Bootstrap that needs to be overridden

```css
* {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You have two `@@` in `media print` remove one of them</strike>. as OP commented this is has to due with the framework in use. - *not an issue*.

You have to set `width/height` when using `background-image`

CSS, comes from cascade, so the `div` has to come after the wildcard selector `*` to override it.

The demo is not using `print` of course.

```css
@media {
  * {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  div {
    background-image: url("//dummyimage.com/200x200") !important;
    background-position: 0px 10px;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Comment: Sorry the double @@ is for the purposes of the razor in the ASP.NET MVC, I will update my question now. but still my question valid

Comment: Ok, still I gave yo other explanations, you can see that now :)